# How should I set up dalli for a dynamic page with lots of content updates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dalli

I know `dalli` (caching) is pretty useful to enhance performance for static sites.
But what about dynamic sites, which are updated quite often?
What is the correct way to set up `dalli`?

One problem I've encountered for example: `dalli` recognizes different params[:page] as the same page when using pagination:(

How would you guys design the system when using `dalli` for both

- the page that gets updated so often
- the page that won't be updated so often

My current code is just like this. That's why I'm facing the pagination problem when using caching...

**controller**

```
caches_page :index, :show
```

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and decided that fragment caching in the views was a better option.

The cache keys for the fragments are based on the models and will change every time a model is updated.

Here is an extract from one of my views in haml.

```
 - @content_pages.each do |content_page|
          - cache(content_page.get_cache_key('home_page_content_page')) do
            ...Render ContentPage model
```

It is based on an approach recommended by 37Signals here
[How key-based cache expiration works](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works)

I have a full write up of the approach on my website here

[Rails caching strategy using key-based approach](http://mark.stratmann.me/content_items/rails-caching-strategy-using-key-based-approach)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only knew the page cahing. lol. Fragment cache seems useful for the pages that are seen by the all users.  However, what if the web application had its own messaging system within site, and all the message contents are totally different depending on each logged-in user? Would you still use fragment cache in that?

Comment: I made new question related to this, with more detailed codes with additional question. So please check and come help me please if you could:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544396/how-can-i-implement-fragment-cache-with-dalli-when-using-pagination-kaminari

Comment: With the user message part the fragment cache should still work if you passed the user's id as one of the array values to the get_cache_keys call.  each user would then generate a cache fragment..  it might fill your cache if you had a great many users.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Up to maximum how many number of users do you think it'll be appropriate to do that messaging caching?

Comment: and If possible, please take a look at my another question with more detailed codes